# 'PhoneGap Desktop' for Android not responding correctly

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I tried to execute my phonegap-project on android and iOS with PhoneGap Desktop. On iOS it works fine, but on android if i click some Buttons, it doesn't work and looks like this:

[image of android issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Ikl.jpg)

I suggest that js is not working ...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a moment to read the how to ask a good question guide. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ernes, if are you really using [Phonegap Desktop](http://app.phonegap.com/), then you should be on [nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). On your app, what is not working as expected.